# SSIS Package Error - Executing through C# Console Application

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

I am new to this thread and i am stuck in a situation where I need to execute the SSIS package via C# console application.

Following is the code which I used to execute the package.

```
Package pkg;
Application app;
DTSExecResult pkgResults;

pkgLocation =@"D:\MIS Reports\TERADATA\Daily_CBASQ1_Loading.dtsx";
app = new Application();
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

But it throws an error :

```
The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 
"Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored."
```

This occurs when `CPackage::LoadFromXML fails`

Please help!

Comment: does your package requires input from config file?

Comment: Have you tried executing that package using `DTEXEC.EXE`? You might get better error messages. What protection level is that package? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is more like Comment but wanted to post code which might help in debugging

You can add EventListener which may help you to capture the actual error.

```
  class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
      {
        public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent, 
          string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
        {

          Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Now Call package like this  and update the actual error in question

```
 MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();
pkgLocation =@"D:\MIS Reports\TERADATA\Daily_CBASQ1_Loading.dtsx";
app = new Application();
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener);
pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);
```

Comment: I already have this piece of code in my console application and the problem still not resolved but thanks for the comment.

Comment: No Problem is not supposed to resolve by adding this code rather you should be able to get more information regarding the error...If you have this code can you post the error...Also, your question I did not see this code thats why suggested it

Answer (score 0):

Please find below my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();


        pkgLocation =@"D:\MIS Reports\TERA DATA\Daily_CBASQ1_Loading.dtsx";
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation,eventListener);
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
{
    public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent,
           string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
    {
        // Output Error Message
        Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error :

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.